# How and where to get the time series of the values USDEUR?

Tags: foreign-exchange, online-data-source, historical-data

I would like to access to the time series of the value of USDEUR with the maximum sampling rate and the maximum length.

I would like to do have this time series because:

1. I want to check the exchange rate of specific day for compare to the exchange rate that my bank use for convert my money.
2. I would like to get knowledge about the this time series for better manage my personal finance and perform better conversion operation.

Is it possible to get such thing, and where can I get it?

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: Mainly for two things: 1 check values at a specific day and 2 for play/make some time series analysis. I don't have any experience so maybe it's not make sense sorry. I guess for 1 there is probably other method.

Comment: This question does not appear to have any relevance to Personal Finance and Money, and should be on hold until such time as the OP provides some indication as to how it is related.

Comment: dukascopy offers free quotes on a tick-by-tick basis

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea is my comment and the edit of the question is good for you?

Comment: @DilipSarwate in plus of the comment that I previously made I edit the question. Is it good now?

Answer (score 2):

The Federal Reserve Bank publishes exchange rate data in their H.10 release.

It is daily, not minute by minute.

The Fed says this about their data:

> About the Release The H.10 weekly release contains daily rates of
>   exchange of major currencies against the U.S. dollar. The data are
>   noon buying rates in New York for cable transfers payable in the
>   listed currencies. The rates have been certified by the Federal
>   Reserve Bank of New York for customs purposes as required by section
>   522 of the amended Tariff Act of 1930.

The historical EURUSD rates for the value of 1 EURO in US$ are at:

http://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/h10/hist/dat00_eu.htm

If you need to know USDEUR the value of 1 US$ in EUROS use division 1.0/EURUSD.

Comment: +1 That's what I use. Very easy to get an automatic download too: http://www.federalreserve.gov/datadownload/Choose.aspx?rel=H10

Comment: +1 but I have hard time to understand what is the meaning of this value. Is it an average value on the day? Is it the minimum? How I get the rate USDEUR from this?

Comment: I edited the answer, hopefully it reflects this.